# How to insert a storyboard into a project folder, and give the project access to it?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a storyboard into my project folder, and give my project access to it.

Something I've tried: When I drag the storyboard into my project and check "copy items if needed", it only creates a reference.  I know this because when I drag the original storyboard from my desktop into the trash, the project cannot find the storyboard.  I need to be able to push a full working project into git.

I want the storyboard from 6 commits ago, and the code from the last commit (which doesn't have a storyboard).  One lame but functional workaround I am considering is getting the code files from the last commit, `git reset --hard <id of 6 commits ago>`, dragging code in, swapping out old code, dragging all files into another folder, `git reset --hard <id of last commit>` then swap in the correct files, `git add --all`, `git commit -m ""`, `git push`, call it a day. I would like not to have to go through such a stupid and length process every time this situation happens.

Comment: Try putting the storyboard in the same folder with your project file in Finder. Then choose "Add Files..." in Xcode and select the storyboard.

Comment: There's nothing special about storyboard; it's just a file like any other file. If you know how to restore a file from 6 commits ago, you know how to restore the storyboard from 6 commits ago, though of course since your project has no storyboard now, the storyboard will be in your project folder but not in your project, until you tell the project about it. There is no need to drag anything anywhere, so it's rather unclear what you're doing and what the desktop has to do with anything.

Comment: @MikeTaverne.  Thank you so much, that worked!  I've spent the last 4 hours trying many permuations.  One thing, after I chose "Add Files" it added the storyboard at top level, then I dragged it between my appDelegate and assets folder where I'm used to it living, however it left a placeholder at the top.  How can I eliminate the placeholder at top, without losing the storyboard?

Comment: @matt, is my edited question clear? Let me know if any part is still confusing.

Comment: @MikeTaverne, if you put what you said as the answer, I will select it as the chosen answer.